# What can we say about $x$?

Tags: inequality

If we have three reals (not positive reals, just reals) $x,y,z$ such that $x^2+3y^2+z^2+(x+y-z)^2=2$, what can we say about $x,y,z$? Is it possible to find the minimum of $x$? I don't know where to begin. However, if we expand and take the $x$ derivative and set $=0$ we get $x=(z-y)/2$.

Thanks.

Comment: Take the partial derivative wrt $x, y$ and $z$ of the function set them to  equal zero and try to solve them to find a critical point for some $(x_{0},y_{0},z_{0})$. Then take the second partial derivaties (all of them) of your function to see the nature of the saddle points etc. Once you know where the minimum is, you can say more about $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get $x_\min=-7/\sqrt{35}$.  Here's how.

Think of the equation as defining $x$ implicitly as a function of $y$ and $z$.  Writing the derivatives of $x$ with respect to $y$ and $z$ as $x_y$ and $x_z$, we have

$$2xx_y+6y+2(x+y-z)(x_y+1)=0$$
and
$$2xx_z+2z+2(x+y-z)(x_z-1)=0$$

To find the critical points for $x$, set $x_y=x_z=0$.  The equations simplify to

$$x=z-4y$$
and
$$x=2z-y$$
which are simplest to solve for $x$ and $z$ in terms of $y$:

$$z=-3y\quad\text{and}\quad x=-7y$$

Plugging these into the original equation produces

$$2=49y^2+3y^2+9y^2+(-7y+y+3y)^2=70y^2$$

so $y^2=1/35$.  The max and min values for $x$ are thus $\pm7/\sqrt{35}$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$$70\times 2=(49+3+9+9) (x^2+3y^2+z^2+(x+y-z)^2) \ge (7x - 3y + 3z +3(x+y-z))^2=100 x^2$$

$$\implies -\sqrt{\frac75} \le x \le \sqrt{\frac75}$$
with equality iff $\dfrac{x^2}{49} = \dfrac{y^2}1 = \dfrac{z^2}9 = \dfrac{(x+y-z)^2}9$